# Jquery quiz - wont call the last if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why won't it call the last `if` after going through all the arrays?

```
//array biblioteket
var startArray = [

    {
        "s1": "Hvor høj er Rundetårnet? ",
        "svar": "34"
    },

    {
        "s1": "hvor gammel er Thomas",
        "svar": "27"
    }
]

var qu = 0;
var score = 0;

//submit knapper kalder funktion info

$("#form").submit(quiz);
$("#question").html(startArray[qu].s1 + "<br/><br/>");

function quiz() {

    var answer = $("#answer").val();

    if (answer == startArray[qu].svar) {
        score++
        $("#comment").html("<h2>" + "Flot arbejde! <br/> <br/>" + "Din Score er: " + score + "</h2>");
        qu++
        $("#question").html(startArray[qu].s1 + "<br/><br/>");
    } else {
        $("#comment").html("<h2>" + "prøv igen <br/> <br/> " + "</h2>");
    }

    if (qu == 2) {

        $("#question").hide();
        $("#form").hide();
        $("#comment").html("Tillykke du er færdig. <br/> <br/>" + "Din Score er: " + score);

    }

    event.preventDefault();
    $("#answer").val('');
}
```

Comment: `qu` is only being incremented if `answer == startArray[qu].svar`  have you checked what values it's incrementing to? If the condition is never true, `qu` will always be 0

Comment: Either `qu` is not 2, or you are an exception is being raised before your code completes.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5p6/ (and then of course submits where it shouldn't)

Comment: it´s have to run this:

$("#comment").html("Tillykke du er færdig. <br/> <br/>" + "Din Score er: " + score);

after running Array[0] and [1]

Answer (score 1):

Change `function quiz()` to `function quiz(event)` so you have a reference to the `event` in the method..

Otherwise your `event.preventDefault();` does not work.. (*it causes an error as `event` is undefined*)

---

You also need to check if there is a next question before trying to show it..

so

```
    qu++;
    if (startArray[qu]){
        $("#question").html(startArray[qu].s1 + "<br/><br/>");
    }
```

Demo with all changes at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Ym5p6/3/

Comment: How is this solving his problem?

Comment: @BotskoNet it stops the form from submitting, which is likely what's making the op think it never reaches 2.

Comment: When I asked the question you had nothing about `preventDefault`, you simply had `function quiz(event)` and nothing else

Comment: @BotskoNet i expanded my question due to your comment, which suggested that it was not clear ..

Comment: do i have the event.prevent... in the right places?
because it doesn't make any difference...

Comment: @ThomasHansen It will work for the first round, but in second round another error occur before you try to show the 3rd question that does not exist.. updated my anwser to explain that as well (*and provided a working demo*)

Answer (score 1):

Put ; after qu++ and score++ otherwise qu will not be incremented.

Also you are using incremented qu value in `$("#question").html(startArray[qu].s1 + "<br/><br/>");` which will be startArray[2].s1 for second question, however it should be startArray[1].s1 for second question.
So change it to:

```
 $("#question").html(startArray[qu-1].s1 + "<br/><br/>");
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: i got that with qu++ and score++ ! :) thanks..

put it won´t the last if after doing all the arrays..
it i change i to qu-1 it will run the same array over and over..

Comment: Or you can swap qu++ and $("#question") without the need to use qu-1. Here is another working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5p6/2/

Comment: yeah it´s doing what i want... but the question dosent change.. ?

Comment: The answer to your question is because when qu = 2; startArray[qu] is not defined. So an error is thrown and code execution is stopped. So it will not go into last if block.